# $(this).css() is producing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a the below code where I would like to check id of an element, but when I put

```
$(this).attr("Id");
```

it returned "undefined". So I checked with

```
.css("width");
```

and it returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined.
```

Below is my code:

```js
function create_login_dialog() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    element_id = $(this).css("width");
    if (element_id == "#login") {
      var login_dialog = "<form id='login_dialog' method='post' action=''></form>";
      $("body").append(login_dialog);
      console.log("logindialog is working");
    } else {
      console.log(element_id);
    }
  });


  console.log("loginquery.js is working");
}
```

```html
<div id="login">the login div</div>
```

Comment: try `.attr("id")` id in lowercase or just `this.id`

Comment: @palasH, did that; still the same

Comment: `$(this).on("click"` what does `this` here refers to and what does `this` inside the click refers to? `console.log` both and check once.

Comment: I think the problem is that `create_login_dialog` dont know what `this` refers to. try with `create_login_dialog(obj)` and then chance `$(this).on("click"` to `$(obj).on("click"`. Also post your html so we hav ea better chance of helping you

Comment: shows [window] for both console.log($(this));

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen, tried your suggestion, it does not console log anything. And I am sorry the html is dynamic, coming from too many linked php files and I can't post it all here.

Comment: If you're trying to listen to the click event bubbling up the DOM, why not just use `$(document).on('click', '#login', function() {...})`?

Comment: @Neo have you tried my answer?

Comment: If its not working use the suggestion of @Terry..

Comment: @Terry you are right, but the problem here is that the code does not recognize the "id", so nothing based on "id" would work.

Comment: Where is `create_login_dialog` fn being called? and on what event you are calling it on body load or else?

Comment: @Shadow Fiend, your's is the best solution so far I'm still working on it

Comment: @palaѕн, I had it called within onLoad and on document ready, both had the same effect.

Comment: and I have no idea about the downvotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the **width** in the variable `element_id`, yet you are comparing it to `#login` one line down:

```
element_id = $(this).css("width");
if (element_id == "#login") {...}
```

I don't understand your logic. If you want to get the ID of the element that triggered the click event, listen to the `event.target` and get its ID attribute. The `event.target` will be the element that have triggered the click event that has bubbled up the DOM:

```
function create_login_dialog() {

  $(document).on("click", function(e) {

    // Get the ID of the element (e.target) that triggered the click event
    var element_id = e.target.id;

    // Check if the element that triggered the click event has an id of "login" (no hash!)
    if (element_id === "login") {
      var login_dialog = "<form id='login_dialog' method='post' action=''></form>";
      $("body").append(login_dialog);
      console.log("logindialog is working");
    } else {
      console.log(element_id);
    }
  });

  console.log("loginquery.js is working");
}
```

### Note / disclaimer

This solution is, however, just a patchy workaround for your logic. Based on intuition, I have a feeling that `create_login_dialog()` will be fired multiple times throughout the duration the user interacts with the page. This will mean that **multiple click event handlers will be bound to the document**. In fact, the entire event binding logic should simply be moved out of the method and into the DOM ready code block.

Alternatively, you should namespace the click event and unbind it using `.off()`, e.g.:

```
// Unbind any click event handlers attached by create_login_dialog
$(document).off("click.loginDialogCreated");

// Bind new click event handler
$(document).on("click.loginDialogCreated", function(e) {...}
```

Comment: This is the working answer. The logic is that when I got "undefined" for "id" I wanted to see the error. So I switched to .css("width") to see what kind of error it is producing. I don't understand much about the unbinding of the event handlers, yet I will use this approach.

Comment: @Neo I've updated my answer on using namespaces in event binding, and how to unbind namespaced events.

Comment: @Neo Whoops, the `.off()` line has a syntax error. Updated :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
$("#login").on("click", function() {
  element_id = $(this).attr("id");
  if (element_id == "#login") {
    var login_dialog = "<form id='login_dialog' method='post' action=''></form>";
    $("body").append(login_dialog);
    console.log("logindialog is working");
  } else {
    console.log(element_id);
  }
});

console.log("loginquery.js is working");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login">the login div</div>
```

Comment: This answer produces the desired effect when running the code snippet, but on my page, the link to the library is called through a php inlcude file. So it does not work on my page.